# ExpressJS App.use Sequence of Routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have the following in `app.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('app.use');
    ...
    next();
});

app.use(app.router);
```

`public` folder have subfolder `images`, `css` and `js`.

After `app.use(app.router);`, I have route definition for returning an image from Amazon S3.

```
app.get('/images/:type/:id', image);
```

The problem is that when a page contain image, `app.use` was called twice. How to prevent it? I want to ignore `/images/*` calling `app.use(function(req, res, next) {});`

Comment: Twice for each image or twice for each page? Here your S3 images are not static so one request will be for page and other will be for S3 image.

Answer (score 2):

In general Express uses middleware connect architecture. Every middleware accepts *next* function which if is called passes the flow to the next middleware. So, in theory if you miss it you could archive what you want:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // check if the route matches amazon file
    if(...amazon file...) {
       // serve image
    } else {
       next();
    }
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```